# Plot bars in plotly from bottom to top even when using negative values on y-axis

Tags: reactjs, plotly, bar-chart, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a power graph with Plotly in Javascript (React). The graph is a plot of power in dBm units on the Y axis like this:

[image]

I've tried to use the property 'layout.yaxis.autorange: '"inversed"', but the problem is that bars are drawn from top to bottom of the graph instead from bottom to top. Being a power graph in decibels this looks ugly visually.

```
var channel1 = {
  x: [
    ['2050','2050','2050'],
    ['PCI 400', 'PCI 404', 'PCI 502']
  ],
  y: [-28, -97, -67],
  type: 'bar',
  marker:{
    color: ['rgba(255,0,0,1)', 'rgba(0,255,0,1)', 'rgba(0,0,255,1)']
  },
};

var channel2 = {
  x: [
    ['5230','5230','5230', '5230'],
    ['PCI 56', 'PCI 82', 'PCI 102', 'PCI 103']
  ],
  y: [-88, -67, -34, -130],
  type: 'bar',
  marker:{
    color: ['rgba(255,0,0,1)', 'rgba(0,255,0,1)', 'rgba(0,0,255,1)', 'rgba(125,68,200,1)']
  },
};

return (
  <Plot
    data={[
      channel1, channel2
    ]}
    layout={{
      showlegend: false,
      barmode: 'group',
      font: {
        family: 'OpenSans',
        size: 12,
        color: '#000',
      },
      margin: {
        l: 50,
        r: 50,
        b: 20,
        t: 20,
        pad: 4
      },
      xaxis: {
        title: 'CHANNEL',
        autorange: true,
        type: 'bar',
        showdividers: true,
      },
      yaxis: {
        title: 'RSRP (dBm)',
        autorange: 'inversed',
        type: 'linear',
      }
    }}
    useResizeHandler={true}
    style={{ width: '100%', height: '325px' }}
    />
)
```

Which gives me the orientation of bars from top to bottom instead the desired orientation:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar problem and gonna use the "base" argument and add a corrected value to the base.

E.g. base=-100, dBm_orig=-52, dBm_calc=100-52=48 -> plot dBm_calc & set base

My final result looks like this:
[RSSI by channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06ksr.png)

https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/
Example from link:

Customizing Individual Bar Base

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

years = ['2016','2017','2018']

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=years, y=[500, 600, 700],
                base=[-500,-600,-700],
                marker_color='crimson',
                name='expenses'))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=years, y=[300, 400, 700],
                base=0,
                marker_color='lightslategrey',
                name='revenue'
                ))

fig.show()
```

Comment: Is this a solution? Or do you have a question?

Comment: It is supposed to show a solution :)